# C^infty approximation of Heaviside step function: definite integral of a bump function

Tags: definite-integrals, distribution-theory, smooth-functions

I'm wondering if there is an analytical form for a $C^\infty$ approximation with a compact support of a Heaviside step function $f(x) = I_{x \geq 0}$. In attempting to construct one, I'm taking [a bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function#Examples)
$$g(x) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)I_{|x| \leq 1}$$
and trying to compute the convolution
$$g*f(t) = \int_\mathbb{R}f(x)g(t-x)dx = \int_{-1}^t \exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)dx$$

Does someone know how to take this integral, or at least construct its analytical or finite series approximation?

Comment: No, you cannot compute this integral explicitly.

Comment: @Hope There is no explicit form for this integral but you can obtain an explicit formulation with another choice of $g$. As $(g *f)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t g(x) dx$ a "good" choice is any bump function with a known antiderivative. For example if you do not require compact support $1/(1+x^2)$ leads tot he well known $\arctan$.

Comment: @Delta-u Another $g(x)$ would be fine as long as it has compact support and all zero derivatives on the border.

Comment: Did you tried something like modifing $1/(1+\exp((2x-1)/(x^2-x)))$ as a piecewise function?